# clear it with their security patrol

Tags: phrases

I am translating this part of movie Blue Thunder, and I don't get it. Could you please help to explain a little bit? Thanks in advance. The context is:

*- How does the computer know she's there?
- The people here, they clear it with their security patrol and then they zap it right to us.*

The pilots in a police helicopter saw a patrol cycle in the driveway to someone's house when they were hovering over the assigned area. They were wondering if the owner was home or not and which patrol officer came to that house. The computer here installed in a helicopter. When it comes to that sentence, it makes me confuse to understand.

Comment: I have no idea what is context and what is quoted speech here, and I don’t get what the actual context of the conversation is at all. Or if anything is quoted speech. I don’t understand what’s going on at all. What is a patrol cycle? What system on what helicopter? What computer?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet -- didn't you see the movie?  It's a conversation between the two pilots of a police helicopter, observing through a infrared camera that a police motorcycle, its engine still warm, is parked in the driveway of a suburban home.  "She" is the homeowner, and she is, uh, entertaining the motorcycle officer.

Comment: But this is really ell.stackexchange.com material.

Comment: @Malvolio Nope, never heard of the movie. Without knowing the context from knowing the movie, I at least can make neither head nor tail of the question at all.

Comment: Well, @JanusBahsJacquet, I don't know why you are wasting your time here, when you should be catching up on mediocre action-thrillers from the early 80s.

Comment: @Malvolio I’m only wasting my time here to avoid doing any actual work. ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, my fault. I could have gave more exact details of my question.

Answer (score 2):

"Clear" in this context means "to obtain authorization"; "zap" means "to transmit electronically".

The subject had notified the security personnel that she was coming home, and security had passed on the information to police.

That movie faltered in a number of area, and dialog was one of them.  When you "clear" something, there is always the possibility of veto.  In this case, it was the woman's own home, so she wasn't "clearing" it with security, she was just notifying them.  And "zap" to mean "transmit" is clunky, a weak attempt at nerd-speak.

Worst line: an excited reporter tells a colleague, "That cop may be the hottest ticket since Horatius at the bridge."  Uh-huh.

Comment: You're welcome, but really, _Blue Thunder_?  The stars,  Roy Scheider, Warren Oates, Candy Clark, Daniel Stern, and Malcolm McDowell, and the director, John Badham, all made much better movies in their careers.